# How to get specific data from a view in a CouchDB document

Tags: json, database, view, nosql, couchdb

I want to count the number of buildings per city in my documents. This one of those documents with the city Kentucky, I have 6 cities in total. When I use `doc._id` it returns the id, but when I use `doc.city` it returns null.
How do I show the sum of building per city?

Document in CouchDB:

```
{
  "_id": "729489bb6702c473bb72254d13003f85",
  "_rev": "1-50da566becf84a0a686853290c2ad8a5",
  "Projects": [
    {
      "city": "Kentucky",
      "amount of people living": "853312",
      "overview": [
        {
          "building": "Center building",
          "amount of people": "150000",
          "teams": [
            {
              "party": "xd",
              "vote": "20000"
            },
            {
              "party": "zh",
              "vote": "20000"
            },
            {
              "party": "gh",
              "vote": "5000"
            },
            {
              "party": "sd",
              "vote": "20000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "building": "Left building",
          "amount of people": "120000",
          "teams": [
            {
              "party": "gh",
              "vote": "20000"
            },
            {
              "party": "sw",
              "vote": "15000"
            },
            {
              "party": "gj",
              "vote": "5000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "building": "Right building",
          "amount of people": "200000",
          "teams": [
            {
              "party": "sd",
              "vote": "20000"
            },
            {
              "party": "gs",
              "vote": "10000"
            },
            {
              "party": "er",
              "vote": "4000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want:

```
Key     | Value
---------------
Kentucky| 3
```

What I tried to use and returned null:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id, doc.building);
}
```

What the result was:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d13003f85","key":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d13003f85","value":null},
{"id":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d13007c22","key":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d13007c22","value":null},
{"id":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d130095fb","key":"729489bb6702c473bb72254d130095fb","value":null}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a good concept about map and reduce functions in CouchDB.
Map function filters your data and emits key value pairs which are sorted by the the key.
Reduce function is used to reduce the results of the map function. Main programming lies in the reduce function to obtain the final result as desired.

For your case, Map function should be like

```
function (doc) {

  for( var i in doc.Projects){

  emit(doc.Projects[i].city,doc.Projects[i].overview);

  }
}
```

and Reduce function should be

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {

   if (rereduce){


     return sum (values);

   }else{


    return values[0].length;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can display the city now, but the (value) sum is returning null?

Comment: `{"rows":[
{"key":"Kentucky","value":3}
]}
`This is my output using the same document and mapreduce functions.